# How does a Macbook handle USB devices? (USB not working correctly)

Tags: macos, usb, catalina

I have this setup right here at my work desk, I am using a **MacBook Pro 2019 13'**:

[image: MacBook Pro Setup]

For some reason the USB-A mouse does not work on `USB-C Port 2`.
[image: MacBook Pro Setup]

I'm a Windows user, and I know that in Windows, each time you insert a USB device it installs a driver in that specific USB port. If you change the device to another port, it will reinstall the driver on the newly established USB port.

On my setup, if I want to use the USB-A mouse on `Port 2`, I have to restart my computer, plug it in `Port 2` and then it works, however it stops working on `Port 1`.

How does MacBook handle USB devices? Is there any reason for this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with another port on the dongle? Or with another USB-C - USB-A thingy?

Comment: @nohillside I only have this dongle :-/   Both USB dongle ports works. Mouse works on `Port 1` on both dongle ports. Neither dongle ports work on `Port 2`

Comment: Have you tried another mouse?

Comment: I did! They have the same behavior, only one port works after laptop boot